# localStorage - get and set

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, local-storage

I am new to React and going through a beginner course on Youtube. In one section, the trainer is explaining about using localStorage of the browser to get and set the items. However, i did not understand why should we call the useEffect with getItem first rather than useEffect with setItem. If i place the setItem code above getItem then it does not work.

Please check the code below

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { uuid } from 'uuidv4';
import './App.css';
import Header from './Header';
import AddContact from './Addcontact';
import ContactList from './ContactList';

function App() {

  const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = "contacts";

  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);

  const addContactHandler = (contact) => {
    console.log(contact);
    setContacts([...contacts, {id: uuid(), ...contact}]);
  }

  const removeContactHandler = (id) => {
    const newContactList = contacts.filter((contact) => {
      return contact.id !== id;
    });

    setContacts(newContactList);
  }
  useEffect(()=>{
    const retrieveContacts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(contacts)));
    if(retrieveContacts) setContacts(retrieveContacts);
  }, [])

  useEffect(()=>{
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(contacts));
  }, [contacts])

  return (
    <div className="ui container">
      <Header/>
      <AddContact addContactHandler={addContactHandler}/>
      <ContactList contacts={contacts} getContactId={removeContactHandler} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that's because your below code is executing after component has been mounted.

```
useEffect(()=>{
localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(contacts));}, [contacts])
```

And because of this it is setting the initial value of contacts into the localStorage again. To avoid this you can set the initial value of contacts to the value you get from the localStorage

```
const [contacts,setContacts] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY)));
useEffect(()=>{
localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(contacts));
}, [contacts])
```

// remove another useEffect

Answer (score 3):

The order of useEffect matters

```
  useEffect(()=>{
    localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(contacts));
  }, [contacts])

  useEffect(()=>{
    const retrieveContacts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(contacts)));
    if(retrieveContacts) setContacts(retrieveContacts);
  }, [])
```

Inverting it like above sets the localStorage empty, because contacts is initialized empty, and then you will get it empty and update your state on the next useEffect

contacts is an empty array when it is initialized:

```
const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);
```

So changing the order is doing the following:

```
localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(contacts));
```

Empty out local storage with []

Retrieve the local storage that we just set to empty:

```
const retrieveContacts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(contacts)));
```

Update our state to empty:

```
if(retrieveContacts) setContacts(retrieveContacts);
```